# pka from molecular dynamics

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, molecular-mechanics

How can one calculate pKa values from first principle calculations, static or dynamics?

I have encountered some works using CPMD where people try to find pKa values from -(i) constrained Molecular Dynamics (MD) and (ii) metadynamics. These are somewhat more intricate ways, I believe. Is there any other simpler ways (theoretical/computational)? Can not we do it from simple MD? 
Please suggest some references as well, if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Initially I tried to use the basic formula for pKa, given in wikipedia..                      $$pK_a=-\ln \left[ \frac{[A^-][H_3O^+]}{[HA][H_2O]}\right].$$For my case, I used this formula as follows, $$pK_a=-\ln \left[ \frac{69\times 2}{31\times 58}\right]=1.12$$ against experimental values of about 2.0. Here the numbers that I used represent not the molar concentration, but rather the proper number of molecule/ion. How well do you think the result is reliable?

Comment: The calculation you suggest would be valid if the given concentrations were at the system's equilibrium. If you don't intend on directly simulating a grand-canonical ensemble, feel free to accept the (only) answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered a free-energy calculation?

That is, calculate the free-energy of the dissociated species and of the neutral one, and calculate the pKa via the formula for activity.

There was [this GROMACS tutorial](http://www.gromacs.org/Documentation/How-tos/pKa), but it seems **the link is broken**.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do now, as you have suggested! I would not be able to use gromacs as my calculations are based on AIMD simulations. For free energy calculations, as statistical physics says, the formula is $F=-kT \ln Z$, where Z be the partition function. How can I calculate Z from MD trajectory?

Comment: If you can't be bothered to look up a 'smart' way, you can do this directly by binning position and momentum space and build a histogram from real-space trajectories (gotten from a MD simulation, of course).